# ERROR: Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory in android

Tags: android, gradle, android-appcompat, gradle-kotlin-dsl, appcompatactivity

I'm not able to use `android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity`. It shows error on `import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;` as follows: **Cannot resolve symbol 'v7'**. I have even added `implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'` in the `build.gradle`.

After setting `android.useAndroidX=true` and `android.enableJetifier` to false in the `gradle.properties`, the above mentioned error resolves but instead, I'm getting an error as follows:  **ERROR: Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.5.0-alpha02] AndroidManifest.xml:24:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:5:5-20:19 to override.** 
 Even after adding `tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory` to `AndroidManifest.xml`, I'm getting the same error.

I'm using `compileSdkVersion 28` and `targetSdkVersion 28`.

Comment: Actually, I have tried all the solutions given in the link that you have provided, but then the error **cannot resolve symbol 'v7'**  shows up again, so that didn't work for me. My aim is to use `android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity` in my android project.

Comment: You need to import `AppCompatActivity` from `androidx` not `android.support.v7`.

Answer (score 0):

This is primarily happening because you are using Androidx with the v28 support library , you can remove the v28 library if you are using the androidx library , if you are using the v28 support library do otherwise.

`androidx.core:core:1.5.0-alpha02`

Well the error says that because androidx core and v28 are conflicting. Use either one. And androidx core also has the same methods as the v7.AppCompatActivity has , so why don't you migrate it to androidx using

`import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity`